# Change values in a powerpoint bar chart with python

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have a powerpoint presentation, which I want to update with new data on a regular basis. I can't find a way to manipulate the data in different charts.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
prs = Presentation('Test_presentation.pptx')

chart = prs.slides[1].shapes[9].chart
chart_data_old = chart.series[0].values
print(chart_data_old)
# I get the correct values here.

chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (1, 2, 3))

chart.replace_data(chart_data)

prs.save()
```

## That's the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/powerpoint Interaktion.py", line 16, in 
    chart.replace_data(chart_data)
  File "/Users/pascal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pptx/chart/chart.py", line 178, in replace_data
    self._workbook.update_from_xlsx_blob(chart_data.xlsx_blob)
  File "/Users/pascal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pptx/parts/chart.py", line 69, in update_from_xlsx_blob
    xlsx_part = self.xlsx_part
  File "/Users/pascal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pptx/parts/chart.py", line 85, in xlsx_part
    return self._chart_part.related_parts[xlsx_part_rId]
KeyError: 'rId2'